# How to get date and time in format like - [Today 10:01:20], [08-jan-17 11:20:51] etc?

Tags: ios, nsdate, datetime-format

I am working on chat apps and I want to send date/time in particular format like Today, yesterday with date. How can I display according to this format?

```
  - (NSString *)relativeDateStringForDate:(NSDate *)date
   {
      NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | 
                       NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:units
                                                               fromDate:date
                                                                  toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                options:0];
  if (components.year > 0) {
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld years ago", (long)components.year];
   } else if (components.month > 0) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld months ago", (long)components.month];
   } else if (components.weekOfYear > 0) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld weeks ago", (long)components.weekOfYear];
   } else if (components.day > 0) {
    if (components.day > 1) {
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days ago", (long)components.day];
    } else {
        return @"Yesterday";
    }
   } else
     {
         return @"Today";
     }
   }
```

I am using above function to get date but I want date time in combined string. So how to pass date/time combine to the above method? Is it possible to send a date time string to this method?

Answer (score 2):

For getting the date in format `[08-jan-17 11:20:51]`, you can use the below code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Convert to new Date Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]
NSLog(@"[%@]",newDate); // this will give you the date in format [08-jan-17 11:20:51]
```

For getting the time in format `[10:01:20]`, you can use the below code

```
// Convert to new Time Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *newTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",newTime); // this will give you the time in format 10:01:20
```

So you can use your code like this -

```
- (NSString *)relativeDateStringForDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // Convert to new Date Format
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"[%@]",newDate);


    // Convert to new Time Format
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *newTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",newTime);


    NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear |
    NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:units
                                                                   fromDate:date
                                                                     toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                    options:0];
    if (components.year > 0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%ld years ago], [%@]", (long)components.year, newDate];
    } else if (components.month > 0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%ld months ago], [%@]", (long)components.month, newDate];
    } else if (components.weekOfYear > 0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%ld weeks ago], [%@]", (long)components.weekOfYear, newDate];
    } else if (components.day > 0) {
        if (components.day > 1) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%ld days ago], [%@]", (long)components.day, newDate];
        } else {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Yesterday %@]",newTime];
        }
    } else
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Today %@]", newTime];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of observations:

1. You want `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth`, not `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`.
2. In order to distinguish between "today" and "yesterday", you can't just get the date components between two `NSDate` objects. You should get the date components (but not time components) of the two dates first, and then get the difference between those two sets of date components.

   As it is, if it's 9am and you're looking at a message from 11pm last night, it will calculate that `day < 1`, and thus it will say "Today 11pm" (which is wrong) rather than "Yesterday 11pm".
3. If you're going to include that "x months ago" string, I'd suggest getting out of the business of building it yourself. Apple has a class that does that for you (`NSDateComponentsFormatter`) and it's localized.

So, pulling that all together, you get something like:

```
- (NSString *)relativeDateStringForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    // get the number of days differences

    NSCalendarUnit units =  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:units fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *nowComponents2 = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDateComponents:dateComponents toDateComponents:nowComponents2 options:0];
    
    if (components.year > 0 || components.month > 0 || components.weekOfMonth > 0 || components.day > 1) {
        NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.allowedUnits = units;
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2;    // set this to whatever you want, but 1 or 2 is often best
        formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [formatter stringFromDateComponents:components], NSLocalizedString(@"ago", @"x days _ago_")];
    } else {
        // build time string
        
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        
        if (components.day == 1) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Yesterday", @"day before today"), timeString];
        } else {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Today", @"well, er, today"), timeString];
        }
    }
}
```

Now, notice that I excluded the time if the date was before yesterday. The time doesn't make sense if the date string is measured in any units greater than days (e.g. the time is meaningless in this string: "3 months ago, 11:20am"). If you want to include the time, you have to include the date (which then renders these relative "ago" strings useless). So you might just get rid of this "ago" portion:

```
- (NSString *)relativeDateStringForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    // get the number of days differences
    
    NSCalendarUnit units =  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:units fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *nowComponents2 = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: NSCalendarUnitDay fromDateComponents:dateComponents toDateComponents:nowComponents2 options:0];
            
    if (components.day > 1) {
        // build date/time string
        
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    } else {
        // build time string
        
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        
        if (components.day == 1) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Yesterday", @"day before today"), timeString];
        } else {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Today", @"well, er, today"), timeString];
        }
    }
}
```

That solves the weird "3 months ago, 11:20am" problem, but then again, it's no longer a relative date/time string.

Another option is to abandon absolute time altogether, and just show a relative string:

```
- (NSString *)relativeDateStringForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;
    NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.allowedUnits = units;
    formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2;
    formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date toDate:[NSDate date]], NSLocalizedString(@"ago", @"x days _ago_")];
}
```

The details of the above samples is less important than the basic concepts, namely:

- Be careful using date components when determining "today" vs "yesterday";
- Use date formatters when trying to create the time strings or date/time strings; and
- Use date components formatters when trying to build a string that represents the amount of time (or days) that has elapsed.